# Kindle Fire minSdkVersion?

Tags: android, kindle, kindle-fire

What is the minimum minSdkVersion to support the new Kindle Fire tablet? I've heard conflicting reports that Amazon's android is based on 2.1 (api level 7) and 2.2 (api level 8).

Comment: Wait until tomorrow when the actually announce the device. Until then anything you've heard / read is speculation and/or was fact but was subject to changing before release.

Comment: Actually the device was announced by Jeff Bezos hours before I asked my question.

Comment: Amazon's AppStore helpdesk offered the following: "Thank you for your interest in Kindle Fire.  The Amazon Appstore for Android will be available instantly on Kindle Fire.  We will be providing more detailed information about the device and how to submit your apps next week.  Please follow us on Twitter (http://twitter.com/amznappstoredev) for the latest updates, or watch for updates to our developer blog (http://www.amazonappstoredev.com)."

Comment: My mistake, thought the announcement was Thursday =/ either way it seems that the actual API level is not set in stone or if it is they have neglected to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's early right now so there's nothing concrete about which version of 2.3 it's running but  MinSDKVersion 8 (which is 2.2) if you want to play it safe or 10 (2.3.3).

[Source](http://thisismynext.com/2011/09/28/amazon-kindle-tablet-pictures-videohands-on/)

Answer (score 10):

Amazon has [posted some info](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html?ref_=pe_132830_21362890#KindleFire). The answer is 2.3.4 (api level 10). I, for one, am glad I don't have to go back to supporting 2.1.

Comment: I only see 2.3.3 in the SDK Manager. Is there something else needed for 2.3.4?

Comment: There's no API changes between 2.3.3 and 2.3.4, it's just bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

The **Kindle Fire** will use: `2.3 Gingerbread`